# Restriction of irreducible representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given a locally compact group $G$ with a compact subgroup $K$.

Assume we are given two irreducible, infinite dimensional, admissible representations $\pi$ and $\pi'$ of $G$.

> What are examples, where $Res_K \pi$ and $Res_K \pi'$ are not isomorphic $K$ representation except for a finite dimensional representation?

Admissible in this context means that $Res_K \pi$ decomposes with finite multiplicity.

I would be mostly interested in examples of reductive groups over local fields. Also what will happen, if we replace irreducible by indecomposable?

If $G$ is connected, let $K$ be its maximal compact subgroup. If $G$ is totally disconnected, let $K$ be open.

> Are there examples, where nuclear representations with linearly independant characters become isomorphic after restriction to $K$?

Comment: What does that mean, "isomorphic up to a finite dimensional representation". Does it mean that there is a morphism from one 
representation to the other with finite dimensional kernel and cockerel? That can't be right, because that there would be many trivial answers to your question, like $\pi$ any infinite dimensional
representation (irreducible admissible) and $\pi'$ the trivial representation.  

Comment: pm, Joël, perhaps "up to a finite dimensional representation" means the multiplicities of the $K$-types are different for only finitely many $K$-types. Of course, there are going to be trivial counter-examples when the representations are not infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in infinite dimensional representations only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Archimedean local fields are ok, then the simplest example probably occurs with $G=GL(2, \mathbb R)$ and $K=SO(2, \mathbb R).$  The irreducible representations of $K$ are in bijection with the integers.  One can construct representations of $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ such that the set of $K$-types is the set of odd integers, the set of even integers, the set of odd integers with absolute value at least (or at most) $2n+1,$ or the set of even integers with absolute value at least (or at most) $2n.$  In particular, one can construct two representations such that the restrictions to $K$ differ by deleting a single representation of $K.$

In a bit more detail, take $s=(s_1, s_2)$ a pair of complex numbers and $\omega=(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ where for $i=1,2,$ $\omega_i$ is either trivial or the sign character.  Consider smooth functions $GL(2, \mathbb R) \to \mathbb C$ such that 
$$
f\left( \begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix} g
\right) 
= |a|^{s_1} \omega_1(a) |d|^{s_2} \omega_2(d) f(g).
$$
The $K$-type corresponding to an integer $n$ will appear in this representation if and only if $(-1)^n = \omega_1(-1)\omega_2(-1).$  (And all have multiplicity one.)  You get reducibility when $s_1-s_2$ is an integer $m$ with this parity.  If $m$ is positive there is a subrepresentation which lives on the $K$-types $\ge m$ in absolute value.  If $m$ is nonpositive, there is a subrepresentation which lives on the $K$-types $\le -m$ in absolute value.

For obvious reasons, the reference I know best is the book Goldfeld and I wrote.  We discuss reducibility of $(\mathfrak{g}, K)$-modules on p. 267.  On p. 332, we give a fairly elementary description of each invariant subspace looks like in the representation of $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ on smooth functions.  I see another reference in the comments as well.

Adding:  in the $p$-adic case a similar phenomenon occurs and may be easier to see.  Take $F$ a nonarchimedean local field with ring of integers $\mathfrak{o}.$  Take $G=GL(2, F)$ and $K=GL(2, \mathfrak{o}).$  Consider the representation $Ind_B^G \chi$ parabolically induced from a character of the Borel subgroup $B$:
$$
\chi\begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix} = |a|^{s_1}|d|^{s_2}.
$$
As a $K$-module $Ind_B^G \chi$ is isomorphic to $Ind_{B\cap K}^K 1$ for all $s_1, s_2.$  (Here "$1$" means the one dimensional trivial representation of $B \cap K$.)  As a $G$-module $Ind_B^G \chi$ is irreducible for most values of $s_1, s_2,$ but if $s_1=s_2$ then the subspace of $Ind_{B\cap K}^K 1$ corresponding to the trivial representation of $K$ is actually a $G$-invariant subspace spanned by the function $g \mapsto |\det g|^{s_1}.$

Comment: This example is okay: Can you please write down the representation in terms of induced representation, so that I can check this myself. I guess via restriction by steps, this is remains true for restriction to $O(2)$. This example you mention, does it stem from the fact $GL(2) = GL(2)^+ \rtimes \{ \pm 1 \}$?

Comment: You can find this series of examples worked out completely in Howe and Tan's book on non-abelian harmonic analysis.

Comment: pm, it works for $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. It stems from the fact that the maximal torus of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ is $\mathbb R^\times\simeq \mathbb R_{>0}\times\lbrace\pm 1\rbrace$.